# Having difficulty with ModelBinding and Dictionary, ASP.NET MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Using the following model, I expect that when the Submit button is hit, the Edit Method to Fire, and the `model` parameter to have the adjusted values. But it keeps returning an instance of the class with all null values. It is as if no model binding ever happens.

```
class Trait
{
 string Name { get; set; }
 // other properties
}

class DesignViewModel
{
 Dictionary<Trait, int> Allocation { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
 var model = new DesignViewModel();

 // retrieve traits from database
 foreach(var trait in Repository.Traits)
   model.Allocation.Add(trait, 0);
 return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(DesignViewModel model)
{
 // nothing works yet, so I don't have a lot of code here... 
}
```

### HTML

### Top Level Page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Areas/Setup/Views/Shared/Setup.master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<OtherModel>" %>
    <% Html.RenderAction("Design", "Test"); %>
```

### Partial View

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DesignViewModel>" %>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Test", FormMethod.Post ) ) {%>
     <div id="eq">
      <% foreach (var trait in Model.Allocations) { %>
      <div style="margin: 15px;">
       <%: trait.Key.Name %>
       <br />
       <span class="slider"></span>
       <%: Html.TextBox(trait.Key.Name, trait.Value,  new { @class = "spent" , @readonly =  "readonly" })%>
      </div>
      <% } %>
     </div>
     <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
     </p>
    <% } %>
```

Comment: Can you show the `<%@ Page` directive for your View? Just to ensure it is bound correctly to your model.

Comment: Okay, so you're using a partial view.  Shouldn't `<% Html.RenderAction("Design", "Test"); %>` be `Html.RenderPartial("Design", Model)`? RenderAction displays the output of the controller action directly into the view. The top level page should be outputting the partial view.

Comment: The Partial View is in a different Controller. It needs to be a RenderAction.

Comment: One thing i noticed (probably not the problem) - but your making the textbox readonly (with the @readonly html attribute). then how can you ever "edit" the model? what is this view intended to do?

Comment: The value is edited through jQuery by using the name of the control and it's .val() attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [HttpPost] to your Edit method for it to be fired during POST requests.

Comment: Technically she doesnt HAVE to. If you don't add any verb decorations, you aren't restricting anything (which is the point of `[HttpPost]`), so by default it will accept `all` HTTP verbs. I think the problem is within the `Html.TextBox` binding.

Comment: I have the POST. I just forgot to put it on the example.

Comment: @Stacey: Does the Edit method fire in your example (but it comes with an empty DesignViewModel) or does it not fire at all?

Comment: @Stacey: This might be just a typo on the sample code, but are the properties on the Trait class public?

Comment: Yes, they are. I just typed up the code quickly. They are all declared public.

Comment: I think the issue is trickier than in seems. This might be a good place to start: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: Agree. Using `TextBoxFor` instead of `TextBox` will also help, as you specify exactly which property of the model you are binding to. Will help expose problems as it's strongly typed.

Comment: But this is a Dictionary. They don't have indexes. I've tried doing it with TextBoxFor and it I can't even get it to compile.

Comment: @Stacey If all else fails, use a custom model binder for this action method. That also gets you some predictability if you are pushing the default model binder beyond its normal line of duty.

Comment: I'm not quite certain how to do that.

Comment: Can anyone show me an example of an IDictionary<T,T> working correctly with ASP.NET MVC 2.0? Maybe I can infer an example from there. All I can find are IList<T>, never Dictionaries.